# how to activate user account in laravel 5.2

Tags: php

I am trying to activate users account of blocked users but I am stuck somewhere in the code. 
Here is my controller action:

```
public function activateAccount()
{
    $id = Auth::user();
    $update = User::find($id);
    $update->update(['isActive' => 'Y']);
    $update->save();
    $responce = array('status' => true);

    echo json_encode($responce);
    return redirect()->back()->with('message','Your Account Activated Successfully!');
}
```

and my route is

```
Route::get('activate/account',['uses' => 'HomeController@activateAccount']);
```

I am getting this error from my controller:

> call to member function update() on null

Can anyone please tell me why this issue appearing and is this the right way of doing it? How to activate users of blocked users? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like update() in laravel.

Remove update and do as like this.

```
public function activateAccount()
{
    $id = Auth::user();
    $update = User::find($id);
    $update->isActive = 'Y';
    $update->save();
    $responce = array('status' => true);

    echo json_encode($responce);
    return redirect()->back()->with('message','Your Account Activated Successfully!');
}
```

Comment: you should chan type of isActive to bool with just 0/1 false/true. for better error handling use: User::findOrFail($id);

Comment: I guess you set enum as a data type for isActive.

Comment: no just boolean which is tiny int of 1 or depending on what database you use. $table->boolean('isActive'); in migrations

Comment: Thanks so much one more thing i want to mention i can activat my user now which was blocker and i want to show button only on thoese user which is deactivated and when i click the button on activate use the button should disappear because user is activated the button should not be there?

Comment: Any help from someone

Comment: @shahzadhussain
You have to find users which is currently blocked..and display a Button with link of activate user.
Once user click on button, User will activate and again you have to find users and no need to display button which user is already activated.